# How to search a text file for multiple matching strings and put the sum value in to an Excel cell

Tags: excel, vba, text, cell

This is probably reasonably simple - I'm trying to write a VBA code that will run through a given text file and collate the values for a given string and then add that in to a cell on my excel spreadsheet.

I have succeeded in the first instance in that I can get the VBA script to read the text file and enter the value for a matching string. However, the issue I have is there are some strings which appear more than once. What I want the code to do is to add all the values it finds for that given value together and put that number in the cell.

This is an example of the code I have written so far -

```
Dim myFile As String, text As String, textline As String

myFile = "C:\Support\test\input.txt"

Open myFile For Input As #1
Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, textline
    text = text & textline
Loop
Close #1

'FEATURES
FeatureA = InStr(text, "FEATURE_A")
FeatureB = InStr(text, "FEATURE_B")
FeatureC = InStr(text, "FEATURE_C")

Range("a1").Value = Mid(text, FeatureA + 9, 3)
Range("a2").Value = Mid(text, FeatureB + 9, 3)
Range("a3").Value = Mid(text, FeatureC + 9, 3)

End Sub
```

I guess I need it to loop around to add the values together but not sure how to do that. So if the dataset looks like the one below, at current my code will pick up the first match and put that value in the cell, it won't continue on the rest of the list. For Feature_C it will only pick up '4' as the value, as opposed to adding all the values it finds for the matching string (4+9)

Example txt -

```
FEATURE_A 1
FEATURE_B 4
FEATURE_C 4
FEATURE_C 9
```

Hope that makes sense, and thanks in advance for the help/suggestions.

Comment: You can collect the features and values in a dictionary, allowing you to combine the values where the features are the same.  Or you can just use `Power Query` if you have Excel 2010 or later, and have a routine that you can use to refresh (or replace) the downloaded data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty rudimentary RegEx pattern but it fulfills your sample requirements.

```
Sub Macro3()
    Dim myFile As String, txt As String, txtl As String
    Dim i As Long, features As Variant

    myFile = "C:\test\input.txt"

    Open myFile For Input As #1
    Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, txtl
        txt = txt & txtl
    Loop
    Close #1

    features = Array("FEATURE_A", "FEATURE_B", "FEATURE_C")

    With Worksheets("sheet2")
        For i = LBound(features) To UBound(features)
            .Cells(1, "A").Offset(i, 0).Resize(1, 2) = _
                Array(features(i), sumFeatures(CStr(features(i)), txt))
        Next i
    End With

End Sub

Function sumFeatures(f As String, t As String) As Double
    Dim n As Long
    Static rgx As Object, cmat As Object

    If rgx Is Nothing Then
        Set rgx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    End If

    sumFeatures = 0

    With rgx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = f & " \d"
        If .Test(t) Then
            Set cmat = .Execute(t)
            'sum the matches
            For n = 0 To cmat.Count - 1
                sumFeatures = sumFeatures + _
                    CDbl(Replace(cmat.Item(n), f, vbNullString, 1, 1, vbTextCompare))
            Next n
        End If
    End With

End Function

FEATURE_A   1
FEATURE_B   4
FEATURE_C   13
```

Comment: this is great. What I believe I need to do is work on the `.pattern` in the rgx function. In truth the lines in the text file have a bit more rubbish in them. So instead of them being **FEATURE_A X** where X is the value I want to pull out, they are actually something like **FEATURE_A DATE RUBBISH X**. Been flicking through [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference) I think the answer is there somewhere!

Comment: You should be able to build a pattern that includes one or more oprional words between FEATURES and the digit you are retrieving.

Answer (score 1):

No real need for VBA.  In Excel 2010+ you can use `Power Query`  (AKA `Get&Transform` in 2016).  And all this can be done via the GUI

- Define your source
- Group the rows by column 1

  - Sum Column 1
- Merge the two columns with some spaces as the separator

Here is the M code, but, as I wrote above, you can do this using the Power Query Editor:

```
let
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\Users\Ron\Desktop\Input.txt"),2,"",null,1252),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Column1"}, {{"Count", each List.Sum([Column2]), type number}}),
    #"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Grouped Rows", {{"Count", type text}}, "en-US"),{"Column1", "Count"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("   ", QuoteStyle.None),"Feature Sums")
in
    #"Merged Columns"
```

You now have a query which you can apply repeatedly to the file.  Either "refreshing" if new data is added, or replacing if that is what you want to do.

[image]

Comment: This is really interesting, I didn't know this was in Excel actually!

Comment: @PeteRichardson `Power Query` is a free, Microsoft supplied add-in for Excel 2010 and later.  `Get & Transform` is included with Excel 2016.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a function to count the occurences of a substring.

```
Function CountOccurences(ByVal Text As String, ByVal SearchString As String) As Long
    Dim length As Long
    length = Len(Text) - Len(Replace(Text, SearchString, ""))
    CountOccurences = length / Len(SearchString)
End Function
```